# Airflow: RScript : Error in library(httr) : there is no package called ‘httr’

Tags: r, docker, rscript

**Requirement**: To install R Packages in Airflow to execute the RScript in Airflow

**Tried**: Below commands in DockerFile

```
# Global Docker Build arguments
ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.3.3
ARG PYTHON_RUNTIME_VERSION=3.8
FROM apache/airflow:${AIRFLOW_VERSION}-python${PYTHON_RUNTIME_VERSION}
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-e", "-u", "-x", "-c"]
USER 0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y r-base r-base-core && \
    rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
RUN R -e "install.packages('httr', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('jsonlite', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
```

**Error** : `Error in library(httr) : there is no package called ‘httr’`

Also Tried another by including in the RScript as

```
install.packages("httr")
install.packages("jsonlite")
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
```

Got error as

```
Running command: ['Rscript', '/opt/airflow/dags/r_scripts/R_script.R']
[2023-01-04, 16:57:58 UTC] {subprocess.py:85} INFO - Output:
[2023-01-04, 16:57:58 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
[2023-01-04, 16:57:58 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
[2023-01-04, 16:57:58 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - Warning in install.packages("httr") :
[2023-01-04, 16:57:58 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -   'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
[2023-01-04, 16:57:58 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - Error in install.packages("httr") : unable to install packages
[2023-01-04, 16:57:58 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - Execution halted
[2023-01-04, 16:57:58 UTC] {subprocess.py:96} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
```

Comment: Since you are installing the packages in your dockerfile, it's unclear to me why you would be trying to install them in your Rscript file as well. Does your dockerfile build without error or do you get the same error message?

Comment: @MrFlick DockerFile has build with no error but when i went inside docker exec and tried running R and then library(httr) it gives error

Comment: I don't see how the `RUN R -e "install.packages('httr', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"` could have run successfully but `library(httr)` would still return "there is no package". Can you share the output of the docker build?

Comment: Is there way I can get full output of the docker build ?I guess i saw some error i couldnot see full error ... What is the solution

Comment: @MrFlick I have added DockerFile in the main post , please check

Answer (score 1):

You are running into errors during compilation that are causing cascading errors. When in trouble building R images, since the docker build process often masks/hides some of the real error messages, I run a container before the installation phase to see what's going on. If we do that, we'll see errors such as:

```
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/airflow/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/curl’
* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
--------------------------- [ANTICONF] --------------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------
tools/version.c:1:10: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/airflow/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/openssl’
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/airflow/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/httr’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmp9dyEo5/downloaded_packages’
```

When you see this, it should be clear: you have OS-level dependencies that are not met. While the CRAN page for `httr` is uninformative here, know that it relies on [`curl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html), which lists:

```
SystemRequirements: libcurl: libcurl-devel (rpm) or libcurl4-openssl-dev (deb).
```

If you dive a little deeper, you'll see that we need to add that package as well as `libssl-dev`.

I only tested against the initial few portions of your `Dockerfile`, but I was able to build this and confirm that R sees these two new packages. (I also took the liberty of installing both packages in one `RUN` line, thinking that fewer images in the build process was a good thing.)

```
ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.3.3
ARG PYTHON_RUNTIME_VERSION=3.8
FROM apache/airflow:${AIRFLOW_VERSION}-python${PYTHON_RUNTIME_VERSION}
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-e", "-u", "-x", "-c"]
USER 0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y r-base r-base-core r-base-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev && \
    rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('httr', 'jsonlite'), repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"
```

The build:

```bash
$ docker build -t myimage .
[+] Building 20.5s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 474B                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/apache/airflow:2.3.3-python3.8                                                                                                                                     0.7s
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/apache/airflow:2.3.3-python3.8@sha256:3a17e765ce209eb6cc551518f3b7ad5e2126d509ca8bdd35232ed2d35f801049                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [2/3] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y r-base r-base-core r-base-dev     libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev &&     rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                                 0.0s
 => [3/3] RUN R -e "install.packages(c('httr', 'jsonlite'), repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"                                                                                                              19.6s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                        0.2s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => => writing image sha256:6271d7deb41211a7fa603a086f8cc24d1249d831546e2fec0293d87d14558312                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/myimage
```

Confirm:

```bash
$ docker run -it --rm myimage bash
The container is run as root user. For security, consider using a regular user account.

root@10f43b1bd4c2:/opt/airflow# ls /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/
R6  askpass  curl  httr  jsonlite  mime  openssl  sys
root@10f43b1bd4c2:/opt/airflow# R

R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) -- "Lost Library Book"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> packageVersion("httr")
[1] ‘1.4.4’
> packageVersion("jsonlite")
[1] ‘1.8.4’
> q("no")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its coz of dependencies were missing. Now it's resolved ... Do we have any R package for `AWS SecretManager`?

Comment: Not sure, but a quick search returned https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/paws/html/secretsmanager.html